# add integer values selected by checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview, adapter

TestListModel.class

```
    public class TestListModel {

    private String testlist_id;
    private String test_price;
    private String test_name;

    private boolean isSelected;

    public TestListModel(String testlist_id, String test_price, String test_name,boolean isSelected) {
        this.testlist_id = testlist_id;
        this.test_price = test_price;
        this.test_name = test_name;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public String getTestlist_id() {
        return testlist_id;
    }

    public void setTestlist_id(String testlist_id) {
        this.testlist_id = testlist_id;
    }

    public String getTest_price() {
        return test_price;
    }

    public void setTest_price(String test_price) {
        this.test_price = test_price;
    }

    public String getTest_name() {
        return test_name;
    }

    public void setTest_name(String test_name) {
        this.test_name = test_name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }
    }
```

JsonResponse.java

```
    public class JSONResponse {

    private TestListModel[] result;

    public TestListModel[] getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(TestListModel[] result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
    }
```

HealthActivity.java

```
    public class HealthServicesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

     /*
    *Api call
    * */
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<TestListModel> data;
    private RecyclerAdapter madapter;

    private Button submitButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_health_services);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        sharePreferenceManager = new SharePreferenceManager<>(getApplicationContext());


        submitButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);


     showcenterid(sharePreferenceManager.getUserLoginData(LoginModel.class));


      initViews();


      submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    /*
    * On Click Listner
    * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

                    case R.id.submit_button:

                        int totalAmount = 0;
                        int totalPrice = 0;
                        String testName = "";
                        String testPrice="";

                        int count = 0;


                        List<TestListModel> stList = ((RecyclerAdapter) madapter)
                                .getTestList();


                       for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
                            TestListModel singleStudent = stList.get(i);

                           //AmountCartModel serialNumber = stList.get(i);


                           if (singleStudent.isSelected() == true) {

                                testName = testName + "\n" + singleStudent.getTest_name().toString();
                                testPrice = testPrice+"\n" + singleStudent.getTest_price().toString();


                                count++;

                                totalAmount = Integer.parseInt(stList.get(i).getTest_price());

                                totalPrice = totalPrice + totalAmount;

                            }
                       }


                        Toast.makeText(HealthServicesActivity.this,
                                "Selected Lists: \n" + testName+ "" + testPrice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();


                        Intent in= new Intent(HealthServicesActivity.this, AmountCartActivity.class);

                        in.putExtra("test_name", testName);
                        in.putExtra("test_price", testPrice);
                        //in.putExtra("total_price",totalPrice);
                        in.putExtra("total_price", totalPrice);
                        in.putExtra("serialNumber", count);
                        startActivity(in);

                        finish();

                        break;



                    /** back Button Click
                    * */
                    case R.id.back_to_add_patient:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PatientActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    break;


            default:
                break;

        }
    }

    /** show center Id in action bar
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    showcenterid(sharePreferenceManager.getUserLoginData(LoginModel.class));
    }
    private void showcenterid(LoginModel userLoginData) {
        centerId.setText(userLoginData.getResult().getGenCenterId());
        centerId.setText(userLoginData.getResult().getGenCenterId().toUpperCase());
        deviceModeName.setText(userLoginData.getResult().getDeviceModeName());
    }


    private void initViews() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.test_list_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadJSON();
    }


    private void loadJSON() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(" http://192.168.1.80/aoplnew/api/")
     //                
     .baseUrl("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        ApiInterface request = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getTestLists();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {

                JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getResult()));
                madapter = new RecyclerAdapter(data);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

HealthRecyclerAdapter.java

```
    public class RecyclerAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<TestListModel> android;

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<TestListModel> android) {
        this.android = android;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_list_row,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.test_name.setText(android.get(position).getTest_name());
        holder.test_price.setText(android.get(position).getTest_price());




        holder.chkSelected.setChecked(android.get(position).isSelected());

        holder.chkSelected.setTag(android.get(position));

        holder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                TestListModel contact = (TestListModel) cb.getTag();

                contact.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                android.get(position).setSelected(cb.isChecked());

                Toast.makeText(
                        v.getContext(),
                        "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is " + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return android.size();
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView test_name;
        private TextView test_price;
        public CheckBox chkSelected;

        public TestListModel testLists;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            test_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_name);
            test_price = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_name);
            chkSelected = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);

        }
    }

    // method to access in activity after updating selection
    public List<TestListModel> getTestList() {
        return android;
    }
```

AmountCartModel.java

```
    public class AmountCartModel {


    private String testName;
    private String testPrice;
    private Integer serialNumber;
    private Integer totalPrice;


    public AmountCartModel() {
        this.testName = testName;
        this.testPrice = testPrice;
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }


    public String getTestName() {
        return testName;
    }

    public void setTestName(String testName) {
        this.testName = testName;
    }

    public String getTestPrice() {
        return testPrice;
    }

    public void setTestPrice(String testPrice) {
        this.testPrice = testPrice;
    }

    public Integer getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }

    public void setSerialNumber(Integer serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }

    public Integer getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }

    public void setTotalPrice(Integer totalPrice) {
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }
    }
```

AmountCartActivity.java

```
    public class AmountCartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @BindView(R.id.total_price)
    TextView totalPriceDisplay;

    SharePreferenceManager<LoginModel> sharePreferenceManager;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    List<AmountCartModel> mydataList ;

    private MyAdapter madapter;

    Bundle extras ;
    String testName="";
    String testPrice="";
    String totalPrice= "";

    int counting = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_amount_cart);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        sharePreferenceManager = new SharePreferenceManager<>(getApplicationContext());


     showcenterid(sharePreferenceManager.getUserLoginData(LoginModel.class));


        mydataList = new ArrayList<>();
        /*
        * Getting Values From BUNDLE
        * */
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {

            testName = extras.getString("test_name");
            testPrice = extras.getString("test_price");
            totalPrice = String.valueOf(extras.getInt("total_price"));

            counting = extras.getInt("serialNumber");

            //Just add your data in list
            AmountCartModel mydata = new AmountCartModel();  // object of Model Class
            mydata.setTestName(testName );
            mydata.setTestPrice(testPrice);

            mydata.setTotalPrice(Integer.valueOf(totalPrice));

            mydata.setSerialNumber(counting);

            mydataList.add(mydata);

            //totalPriceDisplay.setText(totalPrice);

        }


        madapter=new MyAdapter(mydataList);
        madapter.setMyDataList(mydataList);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyler_amount_cart);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);
```

RecyclerAdapter.java  //RecyclerAdapter for AmountCart

```
     public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> 
    {

        private List<AmountCartModel> context;
        private List<AmountCartModel> myDataList;

        public MyAdapter(List<AmountCartModel> context) {
            this.context = context;
            myDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        }



       @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) 
    {

            // Replace with your layout
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.amount_cart_row, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            // Set Your Data here to yout Layout Components..

            // to get Amount
           /* myDataList.get(position).getTestName();
            myDataList.get(position).getTestPrice();*/


            holder.testName.setText(myDataList.get(position).getTestName());

       holder.testPrice.setText(myDataList.get(position).getTestPrice());

       holder.textView2.setText(myDataList.get(position).getSerialNumber());

        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            /*if (myDataList.size() != 0) {
                // return Size of List if not empty!
                return myDataList.size();
            }
            return 0;*/
            return myDataList.size();
        }


        public void setMyDataList(List<AmountCartModel> myDataList) {
            // getting list from Fragment.
            this.myDataList = myDataList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView testName,testPrice,textView2;


            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                // itemView.findViewById

                testName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_name_one);
                testPrice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_price);
                textView2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        startActivity(new 
     Intent(AmountCartActivity.this,HealthServicesActivity.class));
        finish();

    }

}
```

This is my code.

1. Here I am taking HealthActivity and in this class by using recycler view I have displayed testList in recycler view. I am passing testList whichever I am selecting through checkbox to AmountCartActivity of recycler View, And, I am calculating total amount of the selected testList and I am getting the result and that result I am passing to the AmountCart Activity through bundle and I am getting correct result in bundle, but, when I am trying to display total amount in a textView its showing me nothing.

And, my second problem is,

2. I am trying to display serial number to to my AmountCartActivity of recycler view whichever I am selecting from previous HealthCartActivity using checkbox. And, I have implemented some code but I am not getting how to solve it. please help me.

Comment: If you want to get text from selected checkbox then you did not set text for _chkSelected_

Comment: I am trying to get sum in textView and serial number. I guess you are not getting my point

Answer (score 0):

**For Issue#1**

Data should be passed onto the Adapter through constructor. The issue could simply be adding another parameter to the constructor:

```
public MyAdapter(List<AmountCartModel> context, List<AmountCartModel> myDataList) {
                    this.context = context;
                    myDataList = this.myDataList;

                }
```

Or,

To add selection support to a `RecyclerView` instance:

- Determine which selection key type to use, then build a `ItemKeyProvider`.
- Implement `ItemDetailsLookup`: it enables the selection library to access information about RecyclerView items given a MotionEvent.
- Update item Views in `RecyclerView` to reflect that the user has selected or unselected it.
  The selection library does not provide a default visual decoration for the selected items. You must provide this when you implement `onBindViewHolder()` like,

  - In `onBindViewHolder()`, call `setActivated()` (not `setSelected()`) on the View object with true or false (depending on if the item is selected).

Update the styling of the view to represent the activated status.

**For Issue #2**

Try using passing data through intents.

The easiest way to do this would be to pass the serial num to the activity in the Intent you're using to start the activity:

`Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), HealthServicesActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SERIAL_NUM", serialNum);
startActivity(intent);`

Access that intent on next activity

`String sessionId= getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SERIAL_NUM");`